# Angular routerlink with params and getting params

Tags: angular

When I clicked the detail button to go to the Details With `bookingId` so in html:

```html
<button class="disable-btn" [routerLink]="['/profile/request-detail', request.bookingId]">detail</button>
```

and get `bookingId` in detail component so in detail.component.ts:

```js
this.bookingId = this.route.snapshot.params.bookingId;
```

But I have an error:

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'profile/request-detail/1244369'

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you share your app routing file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your path in routing file looks like:

`[path: 'profile/request-detail/:bookingId', component:DetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full']`

Then in `DetailComponent` you can get the `bookingId` from the route:

```js
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.bookingId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('bookingId');
}
```